# NumberField javafx

Tags: javafx-2

I'm new un javafx and I have à little problem with textField.

With this field I get only a string with the getText method.

I don't find how to create a numberField to get a integer instead of a string.

Does exist a field like this or must I create it myself ?

How to do this in this case ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

IntegerField exists in JavaFX, but it is an internal class (for instance, it is used for integer input of color picker). It is package private and cannot be used from outside.

But, you can look on its code, and implement it by yourself. JavaFX is partially opensource. You can download sources and look at this.

```
com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.IntegerField
```

Control's code is very simple, and skin class has a public access. So, it will make a big trouble for you.

BTW, you may file a feature (or request) in jfx jira, about its publishing. Possibly, it will become public sometime later, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Java 8u40 introduced TextFormatter. Now you can do this:

```
TextField numberField = new TextField();
numberField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);
numberField.setTextFormatter(new TextFormatter<>(new NumberStringConverter()));
```